# no such command: 'geoNear', when using geo_near with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, geonear

I want to make look around feature in my app using geo_near 
i already make index on my model

```
  ...

  field :location, Type: Array


  index({ location: "2d" })
  self.create_indexes
```

i already run

> rake db:mongoid:create_indexes

here code i use in my controller

```
  @merchants = Merchant.geo_near([coordinate.first.to_f, coordinate.last.to_f]).max_distance(50)
```

but i got error said :

> Mongo::Error::OperationFailure (no such command: 'geoNear' (59) (on localhost:27017) (on localhost:27017)):

i using mongoid 7, ruby on rails 6.0.2, ruby 2.6.3, mongo 4.2.2

you can see full log trace here [trace_log.txt](https://pastebin.com/c7z7fXMG)

Answer (score 0):

$geoNear command (which is what Mongoid's geo_near method invokes) has been removed in MongoDB server 4.2. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#remove-support-for-the-geonear-command.

The equivalent functionality is available in an aggregation pipeline stage - see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/.